# Django: call API function from inside models

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to call function located in `api.py` file from `models.py`?

If so, what should be done to achieve the result?

Comment: Its just python, import the function and call it.  Just be careful to avoid circular imports as the api often depends on the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
from my_app.api import my_function
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that easily depending on the location of `api.py` file.

**1. At Same Level:**

```
from api import desired_function
```

You can even use relative imports.

```
from .api import desired_function
```

**2. In a different app:**

```
from some_app.api import desired_function
```